# Repeat function a number of times

Tags: google-sheets

I have a calculation where I need to iterate and action several times, as follows:

For a certain count, I need to multiply by 1.1 and floor, so that:
(Assume A1 as base value, and B2 as repeat count)

```
If B2=3, I need:

=FLOOR(1.1 * FLOOR(1.1 * FLOOR(1.1 * A1 )))
```

Is there any way to make the multiplication and flooring occur the number of times indicate in B2 cell?

Note:

```
=FLOOR(A1 * (1.1^B2))
```

Will return bad output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use a custom function. These are written in JavaScript, are a bit slower, and can do pretty much anything. Yours would look like:

```
function floorIt(base, times) {
  var total = Math.floor(base * 1.1)  //start with 'A1' * 1.1
  for (var i = 1; i < times; i++){ 
    total = Math.floor(total * 1.1);  //Multiply by 1.1 by ('B2'-1) times
}
 return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was hoping to find a solution without custom functions. If nothing comes up I'll mark this as best answer. :)